# nightmare/electron, how to carry out different operations depend on whether an element exists?

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare

I want to use [`Nightmare`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) to access a page and do different operations based on whether a specified element exists. I know there is an `exists` function to test whether an element exists on the page, but I don't know how to use it or whether it can be used here. Can someone give me an example on how to do this task? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nightmare is thenable, so if you want to use the return value of an `exists()` function as logic, you can use `.then()` for method chaining. This also goes for `visible()` or `evaluate()` or any function returning a value.

The example I provided searches Stackoverflow if the searchbox selector exists, goes to Google, returns the title and then conditionally logs the result. You can continue chaining logic as necessary.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });  

nightmare
    .goto("http://stackoverflow.com")
    .exists("#search input[type=text]")
    .then(function (result) {
        if (result) {
            return nightmare.type("#search input[type=text]", "javascript\u000d")
        } else {
            console.log("Could not find selector")
        }
    })
    .then(function() {
        return nightmare
            .goto("http://www.google.com")
            .wait(1000)
            .title()
    })
    .then(function (title) {
        if (title == "Google") {
            console.log("title is Google")
        } else {
            console.log("title is not Google")
        }

        return nightmare.end()
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how I could apply this to a class rather than using .type for the searchbox selector